# Как при нажатии открыть новый компонент Vue, передав туда объект?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Я создаю форум на Vue + Laravel. Каждый отдельный пост в форуме - компонент Vue, который содержит в себе объект с полями поста(текст, фото и т.д.). Все посты отображаются корректно. Сделал новый Vue компонент, в котором хочу уже отображать конкретный пост и комментарии. Вопрос - как при нажатии на пост в списке постов мне открывать этот компонент поста с переданным в него объектом. (Как при клике на компонент-пост в списке постов, открыть нужный пост и получить там объект от нужного поста). Извиняюсь, если непонятно объяснил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сам новичок в этом, но как раз подобными вещами занимаюсь сейчас. Попробую присоветовать как сейчас понимаю...

Для каждого поста в таблице постов нужно предусмотреть поле `slug`. Обычно его делают уникальным для однозначного указания на запись в таблице. Но, если в форуме предусмотрены редакции поста, можно этим полем указывать на цепочку редакций поста, плюс дату создания редакции (уникальный составной ключ = `slug` + `created_at`). Собственно, из этой связки и нужно формировать URL.

А вот далее два варианта. Первый - вызывать вьюху для просмотра поста. И второй вариант - делать AJAX-запрос и результат передавать в нужный Vue-компонент. Использовать библиотеку `axios`, которая сразу устанавливается при развертывании нового Laravel-проекта.

Дам две интересные ссылки:

1. [Создание блога на Laravel](https://youtu.be/mXuIOp6LRpc) (там на пальцах о маршрутизации в Laravel)
2. [Использование Laravel + Vue](https://youtu.be/wRGhohwRPe8) (там про компоненты, передачу данных и Vue-маршрутизацию)

Лично мне эти видосы были крайне полезны для начала понимания.

И да... На сколько я понимаю, напрямую vue-компоненты не вызываются. Они должны быть смонтированы с какой-то вьюхой. Либо текущей, либо далее вызываемой.

Comment: Я шарю за axios, вот вью компонент он хранит в себе объект поста, мне нужно при нажатии на этот компонент новую вьюху открыть и туда этот объект передать. Написал роутер линк на эту вьюху, а объект из компонента как передать не пойму, не вижу путей решения через axios.